# How change kCIInputBrightnessKey using slider value in Swift, I'm getting either white or black picture whatever value the slider get

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, uislider, core-image

The minimum value of the slider is -1 the maximum value is +1.

```
    @IBAction func changeContrast(_ sender: UISlider) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let beginImage = CIImage(image: self.myImageView.image!)
        self.filter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls")
        self.filter?.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        self.filter.setValue(sender.value, forKey: kCIInputBrightnessKey)
        print("Current value of the slider - \(sender.value)")
        self.filteredImage = self.filter?.outputImage
        self.myImageView.image = UIImage(cgImage: self.context.createCGImage(self.filteredImage!, from: (self.filteredImage?.extent)!)!)
    }
}
```

[image: Here is how it looks.]

Also this the printed output od the sliders values.

```
Current value of the slider - 0.228814
Current value of the slider - 0.271186
Current value of the slider - 0.322034
Current value of the slider - 0.38983
Current value of the slider - 0.45339
Current value of the slider - 0.525424
Current value of the slider - 0.610169
Current value of the slider - 0.682203
Current value of the slider - 0.75
Current value of the slider - 0.79661
Current value of the slider - 0.847458
Current value of the slider - 0.889831
Current value of the slider - 0.915254
Current value of the slider - 0.927966
```

Comment: I'd recommend converting your CIImage into a UIImage **only** when needed, like when "sharing" an image. Look into using a MTKView for rendering a CIImage - it uses the GPU and will perform much faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the filter works every time in the result image produced from the previous slider changed value , here because of this line

```
let beginImage = CIImage(image: self.myImageView.image!)
```

so you need to reset the imageView's image top of the function by adding this line

```
self.myImageView.image = UIImage(named:"girl")
```

//

```
 @IBAction func changeContrast(_ sender: UISlider) {
    self.myImageView.image = UIImage(named:"girl")
    let beginImage = CIImage(image: self.myImageView.image!)
    self.filter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls")
    self.filter?.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    self.filter.setValue(sender.value, forKey: kCIInputBrightnessKey)
    print("Current value of the slider - \(sender.value)")
    self.filteredImage = self.filter?.outputImage
    self.myImageView.image = UIImage(cgImage: self.context.createCGImage(self.filteredImage!, from: (self.filteredImage?.extent)!)!)
}
```

[image]

Also minimum slider value should be 0 and maximum 1

Comment: I was thinking maybe slider changes its value in background threat, that's why I forced the operation to be done in main. I will delete that, but is there any idea how to synchronize it in a more efficient way?

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not getting what you said. Could you please show in my code snippet where to set image view. In my code, I'm doing it at the end.

Comment: Worked as perfect. Thank you very much. Also, one more question, if you don't mind. I'm making a photo filter app and I understand that it is heavy on memory. So right now it shows me on memory tab 160 MB on iPhone 8 simulator. Is that ok?

Comment: You need to follow best practices to avoid strong references , avoid stacking VCS above each others only <=2 , invalidate timers if they exists , make sure dealloc is called after you pop/dismiss any VC **[weak self]** is a good practise inside closures , anyway I think it's always the case in every multimedia app